# I'm having trouble with my regex matching cases I don't want it to (data validation)

Tags: regex, validation

I'm trying to developing a code validation system for an in-house markup language but I'm having a little trouble due to my inexperience with regexes. The tags in the language follow the format of:

{ tag : number : phrase 1 | phrase 2 ... | phrase n}

where number is a number in the range (3.0, 3.5, 4.0 ... 8.5) and exactly one of the phrases must have an asterisk at its end and there must be at least two phrases. Please note that the tags are case-insensitive and whitespace does not matter.

The regex I'm using is:

```
\{ ?(mw) ?: ?[3-8]{1}(.0|.5)? ?((((\| ?(\w ?)+[\p{P}]? ?)*)+((\| ?(\w\ ?)+[\p{P}]?)* ?\* ?)+((\| ?(\w ?)+[\p{P}]? ?)*)?)|(((\| ?(\w ?)+[\p{P}]? ?)*)?((\| ?(\w ?)+[\p{P}]?)* ?\* ?)+((\| ?(\w ?)+[\p{P}]? ?)*)+))( ?\})
```

which does match the correct case of:

```
{ mw : 3.5 | phrase 1 | phrase 2* | phrase 3}
```

but also the incorrect cases of:

```
{ mw : 3.5 | phrase 1* | phrase 2* | phrase 3} [Two asterisks]
```

and

```
{ mw : 3.5* | phrase 1 | phrase 2* | phrase 3} [An asterisk with the number value]
```

Thanks for any help.

And if anyone wants to offer any insight into how data validation systems typically work I would appreciate the insight.

Comment: It becomes easier to handle if you considere three separate cases (as in the answer by @archeong87): 1) phrases, followed by a phrase with asterisk, 2) phrase with an asterisk, followed by phrases without, and 3) phrase with asterisk, surround by the phrases without.

Comment: @fork0 - That works too, but actually what I've done is: 0-or-more phrases without asterisks, 1 phrase with an asterisk, and 0-or-more phrases without asterisks.  Effectively the same but your wording suggests more use of alternation, ``|``.

Comment: that's a requirement, afraid...

Comment: @fork0 - Hm, I don't believe so; the solution below uses no alternation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
\{\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*([3-8]\.[05])\s*(\|[^|*\n]*)*(\|[^|*\n]*\*\s*)(\|[^|*\n]*)*\}
```

Here's [a demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C%7B%5Cs%2a%28%5Cw%2B%29%5Cs%2a%3A%5Cs%2a%28%5B3-8%5D%5C.%5B05%5D%29%5Cs%2a%28%5C%7C%5B%5E%7C%2a%5Cn%5D%2a%29%2a%28%5C%7C%5B%5E%7C%2a%5Cn%5D%2a%5C%2a%5Cs%2a%29%28%5C%7C%5B%5E%7C%2a%5Cn%5D%2a%29%2a%5C%7D&input=%7B%20mw%20%3A%203.5%20%20%7C%20hello%2C%20%20world%20%20%7C%20says%20%20%7C%20i%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7B%20mw%20%3A%203.5%20%20%7C%20hello%2C%2a%20world%20%20%7C%20says%20%20%7C%20i%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7B%20mw%20%3A%203.5%20%20%7C%20hello%2C%20%20world%2a%20%7C%20says%20%20%7C%20i%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7B%20mw%20%3A%203.5%20%20%7C%20hello%2C%20%20world%20%20%7C%20says%2a%20%7C%20i%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7B%20mw%20%3A%203.5%20%20%7C%20hello%2C%20%20world%20%20%7C%20says%20%20%7C%20i%2a%20%7D%0D%0A%7B%20mw%20%3A%203.5%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7B%20mw%20%3A%203.5%20%20%7C%20%7D%0D%0A%7B%20mw%20%3A%203.5%2a%20%7C%20%7D%0D%0A%7B%20mw%20%3A%203.5%20%20%7C%20hello%2C%20world%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7B%20mw%20%3A%203.5%20%20%7C%20hello%2C%20world%2a%20%7D), tested with the following input:

```
{ mw : 3.5  | hello,  world  | says  | i  }
{ mw : 3.5  | hello,* world  | says  | i  }
{ mw : 3.5  | hello,  world* | says  | i  }
{ mw : 3.5  | hello,  world  | says* | i  }
{ mw : 3.5  | hello,  world  | says  | i* }
{ mw : 3.5    }
{ mw : 3.5  | }
{ mw : 3.5* | }
{ mw : 3.5  | hello, world  }
{ mw : 3.5  | hello, world* }
```

**UPDATE**

Some notes.

1. In your original regex,  `?` says "0 or 1 space characters".  You may have meant `\s*` which means "0 or more whitespace characters".
2. In your original regex, note that `(.0|.5)` actually matches `A0` and `B5`.
3. You may need to modify my regex to reincorporate whatever you were doing with `[\p{P}]?`.
4. It looks like you were on the right track but you may have overcomplicated some things, and most likely something funky with your whitespace expressions messed up your regex.  I encourage using the tool I linked above, [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/), testing your regex piece by piece to see where things aren't working as expected.

**UPDATE 2**

Highly doubt you're able to add flags, but the `x` flag would shorten this regex considerably:

```
\{(\w+):([3-8]\.[05])(\|[^|*\n]*)*(\|[^|*\n]*\*)(\|[^|*\n]*)*\}
```

Comment: I believe the OP asked for "\s*" (whitespace does not matter)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This simplifies things a whole lot, but now I'm having two issues. The regex now only matches phrases of 1 word length (which doesn't make sense because you're using the same \w+ marker that i did). "|hello | world* | says... " works fine but "|hello world* | says..." doesn't.  Also what does (?: mean exactly?

But really this is such a great answer and the regex is much more concise than mine was.

Comment: I removed the ``?:``s, realizing you probably weren't using captures.  It simply says "don't capture this group."  And for some reason I didn't realize you were going for multiple words.  I'll update the answer in a bit.

Comment: Updated the regex, the demo, etc. This warrants a bit of explanation. First, ignore the ``\n``s--you can even remove them--they were only necessary for the demo. Second, ignoring the ``\n``, ``[^|*]*`` means "any string of non-pipe non-asterisk characters." This allows punctuation and unicode characters in your phrases.  The ``\w+`` wasn't working because ``\w`` doesn't include spaces, which are of course necessary for multi-word phrases.

Comment: This disallows the phrases with asterisks in them, right? Like these: `phrase *1`, `*good* phrase`?

Comment: And have you tested it with two phrases with asterisks at the end? (invalid input case)

Comment: @fork0 - Yes, you are right; I started writing one that handles that but it's more involved and I figured the OP would ask if such were a requirement.  No, I missed the double-asterisk case in my demo, but I took for granted it would work, since I have no quantifier on the asterisk case.  Always good to test though!  Thanks for the helpful comments.

Comment: Anyway, I actually agree that using regexes for this loosely defined input is somewhat complicated. I'm giving up at the two asterisks case :)

Comment: This expression matches the following: { mw : 3.5  | * }

Comment: Yes, I left the possibility of blank phrases, in general.  I had originally written the regex in a form that excludes blanks, but it was lengthy, and I didn't even know what OP's data will look like.  Each phrase component would have to be expanded from ``(\|[^|*\n]*)`` to ``(\|[^|*\n]*[^|*\s][^|*\n]*)``.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a place for a proper grammar and using a parsing tool such as yacc, antlr...ect to build the code that will actually do the parsing for you.  Regular expressions can only do so much, but it looks like there may be an inexact definition of your DSL.

That or you will need to use more than a single regular expression to validate your special cases that can not be found using a single expression.

Comment: I would agree if we were talking about HTML or something, which involve recursively nested groups, but this problem has no recursion and is quite easily handled by regex. Problems might arise only if, say, ``|`` was not a phrase separator within nestable brackets like ``()``, ``[]``, and ``{}``.